# Perform different calls (in sequence) using Backbone.Collection and jQuery Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I'm using a code like the following.

```
var firstCollection = new FirstCollection();
$.when( firstCollection.fetch( params1 )).done(function() {

    // here firstCollection has been enriched. It contains the actual data.
    // params2 will depends on firstCollection attirbutes

    var secondCollection = new SecondCollection();
    $.when( secondCollection.fetch( params2 ) ).done(function() {

        // here secondCollection has been enriched. It contains the actual data.
        // move to another screen

    }).fail( function() {

    } );

}).fail(function() {

}).always(function() {

});
```

My goal is to perform two calls in sequence, i.e. perform the fetch of the `firstCollection` and then the fetch of `secondCollection`. The motivation is that second fetch depends on `firstCollection` attributes.

So my question is the following. Is there any better alternative to achieve this with jQuery Deferred or the solution I'm using is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something as this:

```
var firstCollection = new FirstCollection();
var secondCollection = new SecondCollection();

this.listenTo(firstCollection, 'reset', scndfetch);

firstColllection.fetch(params1).then(function(data){  })

scndfetch = function(){
secondCollection.fetch(params2).then(function(data){
    //data has model/collection
});
}
```

When a collection gets loaded an sync/reset event happens. Listen to that and the secondCollection can start loading..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any other approach to follow?